# Cannot access BIOS on a Lenovo U410

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, bios, ideapad

I recently took a step into Linux on my Lenovo Idea pad U410; after a couple hours I managed to get it installed with the drivers. However now I no longer have the ability to access the BIOS. I tried the usual FN+F2, F2,F1,Del,Tab,F12,F11; all to no avail. I was wondering is there something different to be done running Ubuntu? I know that the BIOS would generally not be affected by the OS.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The default option for the U410 to enter the BIOS is Fn+F2 if it is in hotkey mode. 
If it is in legacy mode you need to use F2.   Ubuntu should not change this at all.  Have you tried doing a cold boot and hitting Fn+F2 or F2?

Note: You need to do this *very* early. If you see the Lenovo text logo, it's probably too late. Your best bet is to probably force restart (with OS) and, holding down Fn, keep tapping the F2 key.

Comment: Yes i tried a cold boot and both Fn+F2, and F2 however it does nothing and just boots the OS